# An IF statement that checks and executes a command per each set variables in a windows batch file

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

Updated explanation:
I have a main batch file that branches out with subroutine batch scripts depending on what arguments are used in its execution. So, I need help with grabbing the NAMES of some preset values (only the names, i.e. TRIMAPP1, TRIMAPP2, etc.) and using them as values for the mentioned subroutine scripts.
In part, what Stephan suggested works (the %%a value) to provide me the names, but I then need to be able to use each result concurrently.

```
SET TRIMAPP1=APP1
SET TRIMAPP2=APP2
SET TRIMAPP3=APP3
SET TRIMAPP4=APP4
SET TRIMAPP5=APP5

if [%1%]==[TRIMMER] GOTO ONE 
if not [%1%]==[2] GOTO NEXTSECTION 

:ONE
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('set TRIMAPP') do echo var %%a
```

…then need to run the following with each result for %%a

```
SET BACKUP DIRECTORY=C:\bkp\”%%a” 
SET LOG DIRECTORY=C:\log\”%%a”_Logs
CALL C:\TRIM\TRIMMER.exe.
```

I’m expecting…

```
SET BACKUP DIRECTORY=C:\bkp\TRIMAPP1
SET BACKUP DIRECTORY=C:\bkp\TRIMAPP2
SET BACKUP DIRECTORY=C:\bkp\TRIMAPP3
SET BACKUP DIRECTORY=C:\bkp\TRIMAPP4
SET LOG DIRECTORY=C:\log\TRIMAPP1_Logs
SET LOG DIRECTORY=C:\log\TRIMAPP2_Logs
SET LOG DIRECTORY=C:\log\TRIMAPP3_Logs
SET LOG DIRECTORY=C:\log\TRIMAPP4_Logs
```

I hope this helps to understand better. Sorry for the confusion, I appreciate your patience. Thanks!

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('set TRIMAPP') do echo var %%a has value %%b` should give you a good start. Sadly the rest of your code confuses me, so please be more clear, if you need more help.

Comment: I don't see an `IF` statement in the code you provided.  Nor do I see how the `TRIMPAPP` variables play a role in the rest of the code.  Those variables are not used in the rest of the code.

Comment: Can you please revisit your question, and [edit] it to make your task, and issue, clear and answerable. Currently it does not make sense, and the comments, and answers, thus far provided are guessing your intentions. In order for this site to assist you we need to be able to replicate your environment, task and code. Currently we cannot do that, so your question as it stands is off topic. Please take the [tour], and read through all of the pages of [ask], in order to understand what is required from you, to get the best experience from our site; thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather from your explanation, you seek to use a parameter to search a group of associated variables for a value that matches said parameter.

You can use the method mentioned already by [@Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) and rehashed as a partial answer to pipe the output to Findstr, then Conditionally execute additional commands if the string is found using `&&`. EXAMPLE:

```bat
For /f "tokens=1* Delims==" %%G in ('Set "TRIMMAPP"')Do (
 Echo(%%H|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /LIC:"Str" && (
  Echo(%%G = %%H
 )
)
```

For the sake of using the above method with different search strings, You can make it a function by using a label and calling the label with an argument for the search string.
By using 2 Arguments, You can increase the reusability to allow use with other variable / groups of variables

```bat
@Echo off

SET TRIMAPP1=APP1
SET TRIMAPP2=APP2
SET TRIMAPP3=APP3
SET TRIMAPP4=APP4
SET TRIMAPP5=APP5

For %%i in (2 4)Do Call :FindVal TRIMAPP %%i
Pause
Exit /B 0

:FindVal <Variable prefix> <Search Value>
For /f "tokens=1* Delims==" %%G in ('Set "%~1"')Do (
 Echo("%%H"|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /LIC:"%~2" > nul && (
  Echo(%%G = %%H
 )
)
Exit /B 0
```

Note, the findstr usage should be adjusted depending on whether you are searching for a match that includes the value, or a match that is the exact value.

Answer (score 1):

Something that you may find helpful is the behavior of the `SET` command when there is no equals sign. From `SET/?`, we can see

> SET command invoked with just a variable name, no equal sign or value will display the value of all variables whose prefix matches the name given to the set command.

Thus, running `SET TRIMAPP` will give you:

```
TRIMAPP1=APP1
TRIMAPP2=APP2
TRIMAPP3=APP3
TRIMAPP4=APP4
TRIMAPP5=APP5
```

The `FOR` command can be used to iterate over the output of a command. Using `"TOKENS=1,* DELIMS=="` will split the output before and after the first equals sign, thus:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,* DELIMS==" %%A IN ('SET TRIMAPP') DO (
    REM PERCENT-A CONTAINS THE NAME OF THE VARIABLE
    REM PERCENT-B CONTAINS THE VALUE OF THE VARIABLE
    ECHO.Variable %%A has the value %%B.
)
```

will print

```
Variable TRIMAPP1 has the value APP1.
Variable TRIMAPP2 has the value APP2.
Variable TRIMAPP3 has the value APP3.
Variable TRIMAPP4 has the value APP4.
Variable TRIMAPP5 has the value APP5.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /F "tokens=1*delims==" %%p IN ('set TRIMAPP') DO (
 echo %%%%.p=%%~p %%%%.q=%%~q ^<^<
 SET BACKUP DIRECTORY=C:\bkp\%%p 
 SET LOG DIRECTORY=C:\log\%%pLogs
 CALL C:\TRIM\TRIMMER.exe
)
```

Can't see where the value of the variable `%%p` which is in `%%q` fits in.

Note for the regulars: `%%%%.p` shows as `%%.p` because `%%%%p` is ambiguous. It could mean escaped-%escaped-% or escaped-%valueofmetavariable `p` :(